# Can the given vector be expressed as a linear combination of the other three

Tags: vector-spaces

Four vectors from $\mathbb{R}^4$ are given: 
$$v_1 = (1, -2, 0, 1), v_2 = (0, 1, -1, -3), v_3 = (1, 0, -2, -5), v_4 = (-3, 5, 1, 0)$$
Can the vector $v_4$ be expressed as a linear combination of the other three? The solution given is yes: $$v_4 = av_1 + (2a + 5)v_2 + (-a - 3)v_3 \qquad a ∈ \mathbb{R}$$
I tried to solve the system of linear equations $\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 + \gamma v_3 = a v_4$, but this seems to get me nowhere. How can I express $v_4$ as a linear combination of the other three?

Comment: You solve the following system of equations : $\alpha v_1+\beta v_2+\gamma v_3=v_4$. You don't need the $a$ in your system, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ only will suffice

Comment: I tried this but I always end up with $0 = 0$, which does not provide me with a solution

Comment: Note that $v_3$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, so if your equation (after having eliminated the unnecessary $a$) has any solutions at all, it will have an infinite number of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is:

$$ av_1+(5+2a)v_2+(-3-a) v_3 = v_4$$

for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, as stated. Here's why...

Firstly write $\alpha v_1+\beta v_2+\gamma v_3 = v_4$ out as

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}\alpha+\gamma \\-2\alpha+\beta \\-\beta-2\gamma \\ \alpha-3\beta-5\gamma\end{matrix}\right) = 
\left(\begin{matrix}-3 \\5 \\1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)
$$

(I've obviously swapped your row vectors for column vectors.)

If a solution exists for the whole vector, then a solution must exist for its first three elements, so we might as well just work with the following to start with:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}\alpha+\gamma \\-2\alpha+\beta \\-\beta-2\gamma \\\end{matrix}\right) = 
\left(\begin{matrix}-3 \\5 \\1 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Re-writing this as a matrix equation, we have:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\-2 & 1 & 0 \\0 & -1 & -2 \\\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}\alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \\\end{matrix}\right) = 
\left(\begin{matrix}-3 \\5 \\1 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

The determinant of the matrix here is $0$, so we may put $\alpha=a$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary constant. Continuing to solve, we find $\beta=5+2a$ and $\gamma=-3-a$. These values also work to make $\alpha-3\beta-5\gamma=0$ (the fourth element of the original vector equation), so we have the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can!

Because we have:
 $$v_4=-2v_1+v_2-v_3$$

Comment: A note about how you found the linear combination would be welcome.  Even if you found it "by inspection", rather than by solving a linear system, some ideas about "how to look for it" may help future Readers.

Comment: @hardmath In our case I solves the system, but indeed, sometimes it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

Note that $$\det \begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&0&1\\
0&1&-1&-3\\
1&0&-2&-5\\
-3&5&1&0
\end{bmatrix} =0$$

Thus these vectors are linearly dependent, which means we can express one in terms of the others. We can see by inspection that $v_4 = -3v_1-v_2$

Comment: Knowing that the determinant is zero tells us that *one* of the four vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of the others, but it doesn't tell us that $v_4$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

Comment: Thanks for the note . Please check my edit.

Comment: I don't see how the first coordinate of $v_4$ being $-3$ implies "we can solve for $v_4$ in terms of the other" vectors.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @hardmath, $v_3$ is quite obviously equal to $v_1+2v_2$, so you can’t draw any conclusions about $v_4$ from the determinant.

Answer (score -1):

In your set: $\;v_4\;$ is a linear combination of the other three vectors iff when we form the corresponding matrix with $\;v_4\;$ the last row and we reduce it by rows, this last row becomes all zeros (why?! This must be clear in order to be sure what is going on here...):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&-2&0&1\\
0&1&-1&-3\\
1&0&-2&-5\\
-3&5&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&-2&0&1\\
0&1&-1&-3\\
0&2&-2&-6\\
0&-1&1&3
\end{pmatrix}$$

...and we're done as we can see the last row is the third one multiplied by $\;-\frac12\;$ .